# Getting POST content type error

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error everytime I run my code.

```
SUCCESS: {
error =     {
    message = "Invalid request (check that your POST content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded). If you have any questions, we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.";
    type = "invalid_request_error";
};
}
```

I am using Alamofire to accomplish this, below is the code that I have made.

```
 func alamoTest(){
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization":"Bearer test_keyxxxxx"]
    let url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts"
    let params = ["managed":"true","country":"us"]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {(response) in
        print("this is what comes out", response)
        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print("Response:\(json)")
        }
}

}
```

Comment: It's because you're using JSON.  You need to set the `Content-Type`-header of your request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Basically, this means that your data blobs aren't being sent to Stripe as JSON, they need to be sent to Stripe as a query-string (in more or less words).

Answer (score 0):

in docs i read that this is a GET request - not a POST request to this endpoint

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
  -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
  -d country=US \
  -d managed=true
```

btw: why not did you try to use the stripe SDK: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I tried the stripe SDK but I want to be able to save the credit card that the user entered, so my thought process is to create a stripe account for them, and then save their credit card

Comment: did you really try to phishing a credit card what the user expect only to share with stripe and not with you?